# error message - openssl: command not found

Tags: bash, scripting, openssl, command-not-found

I am writing a simple script to check if the certificate for a website is valid. However, when I attempt to run the code in terminal, I receive an error message stating that the command `openssl` cannot be found. Here is the code:

```
if true | openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 2>/dev/null | \
  openssl x509 -noout -checkend 0; then
  echo "Certificate is not expired"
else
  echo "Certificate is expired"
fi
```

When I attempt to run this code, I receive this output:

```
./check-certificates.sh: line 6:  openssl: command not found
Certificate is expired
```

The code runs, but it does not recognise `openssl` as a valid command, so it skips over the line of code where this is mentioned, and defaults to outputting "Certificate is expired".

When using `sudo apt-get install openssl` I receive this message:

```
...
openssl is already the newest version (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.15).
...
```

So it looks like `openssl` has been successfully installed. I'm at a loss on how to fix this - does anybody have any ideas?

---

As requested, here is the output of `apropos openssl | grep "OpenSSL command line tool"`:

```
openssl (1ssl)       - OpenSSL command line tool
```

And `locate openssl | grep /usr/bin`:

```
usr/bin/openssl
```

Comment: Add the output of `apropos openssl | grep "OpenSSL command line tool"` and `locate openssl | grep /usr/bin` to your question.

Comment: Provide full path to `openssl` binary or add it to you `PATH` variable. You can find out where it is located by running `whereis openssl`

Comment: `dpkg --listfiles openssl | more` to see where it's dropped the openssl executable.  It clearly isn't in your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note the extra space in the error message:

```
./check-certificates.sh: line 6:  openssl: command not found
```

This means that the command that the shell is looking for isn’t `openssl`, it’s  `openssl`, probably with an unbreakable space pre-prended.

You need to edit your script to make absolutely sure that the space before `openssl` is a “normal” space, or even delete it.

See [Why is this command not working: "ps aux | grep xscreensaver"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/184979/86440) for a similar instance with a bit more info.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - this did not resolve the problem, I still receive the same exact error message, including the space, when I deleted the spaces before and after the pipe. But you may be on to something regarding the extra space in the error message, that's likely the key to fix the problem

Comment: @Stephen Kitt is right.... You just probably forgot one space, since `openssl` is called twice on the line with, for the two times, an extra unbreakable space, probably due to the fact that you hit `space` without releasing the `alt-gr` key... French keyboard, isn't it ? ;-p

Comment: I fixed the problem - noob error. The main line of text is all on one line in my script, therefore there was a space after the /, causing the shell to add a space before the openssl command. Your comment helped me identify the problem though, thanks very much for your help.